# Query builder in Laravel in not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have sql query that is working fine in MySQL. I want to get profile id from profiles table using join with user table.

```php
SELECT profiles.profile_id FROM profiles 
   left JOIN users on profiles.id = users.id where users.id = 1
```

Laravel Query builder query is

```php
    $my_user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $my_id =   DB::table('profiles')->select('profiles.profile_id')
                   ->leftjoin('users','users.id' ,'=' ,'profiles.id')
                   ->pluck('profiles.profile_id')
                   ->where('users.id',$my_user_id)
                   ->first();
```

Comment: Is it neccesary to use `joins`? I think you could define a relationship (just in Laravel, not neccessarely in your DB) to pull the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `where()` before `pluck()` (`select()` is not necessary):

```php
 $my_id = DB::table('profiles')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=' , 'profiles.id')
    ->where('users.id', $my_user_id)
    ->pluck('profiles.profile_id')
    ->first();
```

You can also shorten it with `value()`:

```php
$my_id = DB::table('profiles')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=' , 'profiles.id')
    ->where('users.id', $my_user_id)
    ->value('profiles.profile_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select the id as well to perform the join :

```php
DB::table('profiles')->select('profiles.profile_id', 'profiles.id')
                     ->leftjoin('users','users.id' ,'=' ,'profiles.id')
                     ->where('users.id',$my_user_id)
                     ->pluck('profiles.profile_id')
                     ->first();
```

Comment: this query still not returning nothing. SQL query is running fine but this laravel query is not working.

Comment: What about using relationships ?

Comment: where clause will come first then pluck, now its solved.

Comment: But you have to select the id as well isn't it ?